# How is max distributing over addition in this semi-formal proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-explanation, arithmetic

There is a small proof (semi-formal I think) I am reading that as part of it has (the $\uparrow$ means the maximum function):

$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$=$  {distributive of addition over max, arithmetic} `<=====?`
$t.q\uparrow(t.r + (t.q - t.p))$
$\geq$  {$t.p \leq t.q$, monotonicity of max} (*)
$t.q\uparrow t.r$

Where I have the `<=====?`  it is the explanation given of how we move from each step to the next one, but I don't really understand it.
Could someone please explain how the distribution of adition over max worked in this case (or in general)?

Because what I can see is that:
$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
there are 2 cases:
**Case 1:** $t.p > t.r$
So:
$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$t.p + t.q - t.p$
$\equiv$
$t.q$

**Case 2**: $t.p < t.r$
So:
$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$tr + t.q - t.p$

Since we can have either Case $1$ or Case $2$ the max is:
$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p) \equiv t.q\uparrow tr + t.q - t.p$

Which is what the proof states but it seems based on the wording that there is some fundamental operation that could be applied without needing to do this case analysis? I am looking for that explanation with this post

Comment: Why the close? Is there something I can do to improve the question?

Comment: This is very hard to understand. What is the proof about? What do you mean by "distribution of addition over max"?

Comment: @K.defaoite: That is not mine. It is written exactly like that as part of the steps of the proof. I could not understand what it meant. I thought it is some property that it would be obvious to others how it could be applied but just couldn't understand it. I also updated the post. Please have a look and let me know if it is any better

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand this either. What source is this from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what's worth I figured out what that means:
$t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$t.p+ (t.q - t.p)\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$t.p+ t.q - t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$t.q + t.p - t.p\uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$
$\equiv$
$t.q \uparrow t.r + (t.q - t.p)$

So that should be the distributive property of addition over max